# Firebase Cloud Message (FCM) : trying to send message to device from PHP (error: InvalidRegistration)

Tags: php, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push messages from PHP but I'm getting the following error message:

```
 {"multicast_id":4832091122368281316,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

I suppose there is a mismatch with the browser ID but I don't know which one I'm supposed to use.

When I register the push notification through JS, I receive the following payload on my PHP server:

{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/XXX:YYY","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"ZZZ","auth":"AAA"}}

To send the message in PHP, I have used the following code (found on stackexchange):

```
function sendnotification($to, $title, $message, $img = "", $datapayload = "")
{
    $msg = urlencode($message);
    $data = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'sound' => "default",
        'msg'=>$msg,
        'data'=>$datapayload,
        'body'=>$message,
        'color' => "#79bc64"
        );

    if($img)
        {
            $data["image"] = $img;
            $data["style"] = "picture";
            $data["picture"] = $img;
        }
        
    $fields = array(
        'to'=>$to,
        'notification'=>$data,
        'data'=>$datapayload,
        "priority" => "high",
        );
        
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=MYSERVERKEY',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $result;
```

I think I'm using the right server key, when I don't, I get a different error message.

For $to, I'm wondering what I should use. I thought I had to use XXX:YYY after the endpoint but it's not working (XXX is very short, YYY is very long). I have also tried ZZZ and AAA but it doesn't help either.

My questions:

What kind of ID should I be using to send the message to one specific browser ?

What should I do to send a notification to all registered browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to make sure store the token of your user browser, which you can only get when they allow on request prompt e.g.

[image]

On user Allow the request it generate the token which look like as below

[image]

This token you can use for send the message to specific browser.

So in your code where as your $to = it should be the device token.

i.e. "to": "<DEVICE_REGISTRATION_TOKEN>"

Comment: Thanks! I have posted the JSON sent to the server when registering the browser but I have tried all combinations XXX/YYY/ZZZ or AAA (see above) and I don't know which one is supposed to be the token from the browser. From what I see in your answer I would say XXX:YYY but I'm not sure.